# asp.net mvc account model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to know is it possible to extend membership model for users in asp.net mvc3.
I want to add little more info about user like, City, State, or web site and picture url.

So i update my register model in default account models register user goes fine but i don't know does it store other info, i only can find username and email.

Does anybody know how to extend this model, made changes in default tables?

I am using default account controller and models with asp.net mvc3.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it, the information you want to add, is not really Membership information. I'd recommend you use a [profile provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/014bec1k.aspx) instead.

Comment: do you have any tutorial or examples how to do it, i was thinking that it would be simple to do.